# How can I make this C# Login Form Case Sensitive?

Tags: c#

```
private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\sesha\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Achievers - Grocery Management System\Login Database\Login DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    string query = "Select * from [Table] where username = '" + textBoxUsername.Text.Trim() + "' and password = '" + textBoxPassword.Text.Trim() + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.ToString() == "1")
    {
        Dashboard objDashboard = new Dashboard();
        this.Hide();
        objDashboard.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Check your username and password");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're open to SQL injection.  You should start using parameters instead of concatenation.

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL Injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com)! And the way you do it, case sensitivity is decided by your db. So you can either set the correct collation for the `username` column or fetch the matching rows and compare them case sensitiv on client side.

Comment: You should also hash the password stored in the database using something like bcrypt. Never, ever, ever use plaintext for password storage

Comment: It's your database not the form. Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations

Comment: [xkcd Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: `dt.Rows` is a `DataRowCollection` and not the number of rows. You also don't need to convert a number to string before you compare it. Replace `dt.Rows.ToString() == "1"` with `dt.Rows.Count  == 1`

Comment: @SeshanTennyson please please please be paying attention to the comments above. You will get hacked if you do things the way you are doing.

Comment: Avoid Select * in code

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp), it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no control on how your database is created

Query your database with just the username

Fill a datatable with your fields

Use the values in ur datatable for comparison using `String.compare` 
(remember to hash your password before saving and hash your input for comparision)

Comment: You can't "unhash" a properly hashed password

Comment: You should mention what he should do if he _has_ control over the database, because he didn't mention the opposite. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your posted code, instead of just relying on the comparison in the SQL `WHERE` clause to do the check for you, if a matching row is found then you could re-check the entered value using a case-sensitive comparison against the value of the `password` column of your `DataTable` (`dt`).

If the password was stored in the database in a hashed format, the hashing algorithm would take care of the case sensitivity as any difference in the case of the value entered would result in a different hash value. As many comments have stated, when storing passwords, the password should never be stored in plain text. As a bare minimum the password should be hashed, preferably it should also be salted before being hashed.

Finally, you could look at changing the database collation, if you have access to make changes to the database itself. By default, SQL Server uses a collation which is not case sensitive. For more information, read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations (as commented by Tim on your question).